# PHP - Foreach variable works only if read

Tags: php

I am trying to read posts under each category as shown below. There are multiple categories with id "4", "3", "2", "1". Only for category "1" there is a post available.

```
foreach ($wp_categories as $wp_category) {

  $id = $wp_category->term_taxonomy_id;
  //if($id == "1") {
   $posts = $json_api->introspector->get_posts(array(
                  'cat' => $id
                  ));
  //}
  $result[] = $posts;         
}

return $result;
```

In the above code if I just uncomment the if condition, I am getting the posts in the result array. But if this is commented I am not getting the posts in result.

I am new to PHP and above condition is not making any sense. It would be of great help if someone could explain why having the if condition is making the post available in the result.

dumping $wp_categories below

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "0": {
    "term_id": "5",
    "name": "Category 5",
    "slug": "category5",
    "term_group": "0",
    "term_order": "1",
    "term_taxonomy_id": "5",
    "taxonomy": "category",
    "description": "",
    "parent": "0",
    "count": "0"
  },
  "1": {
    "term_id": "2",
    "name": "Category 4",
    "slug": "category4",
    "term_group": "0",
    "term_order": "2",
    "term_taxonomy_id": "2",
    "taxonomy": "category",
    "description": "",
    "parent": "0",
    "count": "0"
  },
  "2": {
    "term_id": "3",
    "name": "Category 3",
    "slug": "category3",
    "term_group": "0",
    "term_order": "3",
    "term_taxonomy_id": "3",
    "taxonomy": "category",
    "description": "",
    "parent": "0",
    "count": "0"
  },
  "3": {
    "term_id": "4",
    "name": "abc",
    "slug": "abc",
    "term_group": "0",
    "term_order": "4",
    "term_taxonomy_id": "4",
    "taxonomy": "category",
    "description": "",
    "parent": "0",
    "count": "0"
  },
  "4": {
    "term_id": "1",
    "name": "Others",
    "slug": "others",
    "term_group": "0",
    "term_order": "5",
    "term_taxonomy_id": "1",
    "taxonomy": "category",
    "description": "",
    "parent": "0",
    "count": "1"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please print the `$wp_categories` array here.

Comment: Have you tried echoing $id?

Comment: if you leave the comment alone it will not show any post?

Comment: @Goikiu If I have the line uncommented - It will exactly show the post under category "1" . If I comment ideally the post which was shown before should be there, but for some XYZ reasons it is displaying nothing.

Comment: @rybo111 - No but, if condition proves that at some time id is "1"

Comment: Would you dump `$result` when there is no if condition? update your question with that.

Comment: this is in json format.did you `json_decode` it?

Comment: There was a problem with the downstream component. `$json_api->introspector->get_posts` was internally using some mechanism which was messing up when called inside a loop. Fixed it by using WP's get_posts

Answer (score 0):

This is simply shows that it will be true only in case of id 1:

```
if($id == "1") {
```

I think this should be:

```
if(isset($id) && $id != '') {
```

to get the all the post.

Comment: actually he says that he only has post in category 1 that's why he's trying to check for category 1 only.

Comment: @rccoros OP says that `if this is commented I am not getting the posts in result.` means he is not getting the results where is not.

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ - Ideally there should be no check. But adding this check also returns nothing.

Comment: There was a problem with the downstream component. `$json_api->introspector->get_posts` was internally using some mechanism which was messing up when called inside a loop. Fixed it by using WP's `get_posts`

Comment: @Ramesh You can see in your updated code that there is only data for id 1 as it has count 1 and other has the count 0 it means that don't have the data. so it is working correctly.